# Is Jon going to muss Arya's hair already?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire, jon-snow

One thing which is by heavily emphasized in most of the books in the series is how much Jon likes to muss his sister's hair.  It is constantly being recalled from both his and Arya's perspective.

So, here comes my question: Will Jon Snow and Arya Stark reunite? And if that happens, will he muss her hair?

Comment: This question seems to be 80% rant against hair mussing and 20% speculation. I don't see what answer you're expecting to get, really.

Comment: This sort of ties-in to the fact that originally, GRRM had planned for a Jon/Arya relationship, but later changed his mind. There are still instances of these early "clues" strewn about the first book(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conclusion of the last book, *A Dance with Dragons*, suggests this is not a likely outcome, since ...

> Jon dies

... however who believes such an event unless there's corroborating evidence in GRRM's world. In fact, given his pattern about similar events, chances are, it's a feint.

If reunion *is* in order, chances are he'd make to do the semi-regular mussing and think twice seeing as Arya has grown significantly and changed from the little girl he once knew.

Comment: I don't think spoiler tags work in comments, so I'll just point out that your hidden text has happened to other characters with unexpected results...

Comment: @Ward Oh, yeah, totally. That's what I meant about not believing such an event without having other evidence; like an alternate PoV. GRRM is pretty infamous (in my opinion) for using the 1st person perspective to be cunningly deceptive.

Comment: You should be aware that GRRM does not like fan fiction, and has asked that people to not do it. http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/FAQ/Entry/How_does_Mr_Martin_feel_about_A_Song_of_Ice_and_Fire_fan_fiction/

Comment: @TLP Yeah, I'm not a fan fictioneer myself. That was just an attempt at being creative regarding how it'd likely occur. A way of saying, it could be mentioned but may not happen in re-union. I'll change it out of respect for GRRM - maybe it'll inspire him to finish the last 2 books before 2020. :)

Comment: @Josh One can always hope... =P When I consider that it was like 12 years between ASOS and ADWD, it makes me sad.

Comment: as to the spoiler text I may be misremembering but I dont think its confirmed

Answer (score 1):

At this point in time, who knows?

We're still two books away from the end. Who can even say either Jon or Arya are going to survive to see it.

Comment: "Who knows?" as an answer, and you get the only upvote for it... =P

Answer (score 1):

I'd say there's a fair chance that Arya hears about (ADWD spoiler)...

> Jon's assassination, since news from the wall seems to come fairly often to Braavos. When she does, there's a good chance she goes there to avenge him, in her new role as assassin.

Also, regarding prophecies, there's a good chance we see Daenerys going to meet Jon. In the prophecy from the house of the Undying, there's a line that goes:

> *A blue flower grew from a chink in a wall of ice, and filled the air with sweetness...mother of dragons...bride of death...*

The blue flower is a reference to Lyanna, wall of ice is wall of ice. The passage seems to refer to Dany's husbands and/or significant love interests.